# Eclipse for C++

Tags: pi-3

How do I install Eclipse for C++?

I do not do Java, so I am just guessing the canned version in Raspian is Eclipse for Java since there is no C++ sample code.

I do not want to uninstall this Java version until I can get the most current version Eclipse for C++ working.

This is the  terminal output I get:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install Eclipse
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
eclipse is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgconf2-4 libgnome2-0 lxkeymap python-gobject python-xklavier triggerhappy
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am very dubious any Pi has enough memory to run Eclipse effectively.  Doesn't hurt to try though.

`apt search eclipse` shows a bunch of additional packages, including `eclipse-cdt`, described as "C/C++ Development Tools For Eclipse".

Note that just because a piece of software is available through Raspbian doesn't mean it's actually going to work well. The reason it's there is because it is in Debian. I mention this because if it doesn't work, that's not a bug, that's just a puny little box with 1 GB of RAM.

Comment: Thanks for partially on the subject answer. I shall rate the answer after I get it loaded and running

Comment: OK , it is loaded.Not really sure I got the latest C++ eclipse because I cannot verify / update Eclipse software. As far as "1GB" RAM being puny I wish we can discuss that....I am more concerned if my Debian is 32 or 64 bit OS... again cannot discuss that ether. For those reasons I cannot mark this thread as "answered" .

Comment: It probably will not be the very latest version because Debian has a conservative policy WRT versioning.

Comment: Eclipse has it own weird  versioning / naming system , but I cannot even get Raspbery to run single "update" nor show that I have CDT version installed.

Comment: Eclipse has it own weird  versioning / naming system , but I cannot even get Raspberry to run single "update" nor show that I have CDT version installed.I did installed CDT 9.2 and still have Eclipse 3.8 icon on desktop. From last comment - I do not want  to use / rely OS which tells me what app "they think" is OK. I am abandoning Raspberry Pi 3 B as a development system.

Answer (score 0):

After unistalling the current version of Eclipse 3.8 I used sudo apt-get install eclipse.

It worked and installed  SAME version Eclipse 3.8 
Works as expected, still trying for Eclipse Oxygen.